# custom log grok pattern

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

I am trying to parse a custom log line using grok pattern but I'm not able to completely parse the line.

Custom log line:

```
site 'TRT' : alias 'TRT,FAK,FAS,ATI,ONE,DVZ,TWO' : serveur 'Test10011' RAS : TRT / TRT serveur 'Test10011' OK
```

Grok pattern:

```
%{DATA:site}\:%{DATA:alias}\:%{DATA:server}\:%{DATA:msg}
```

Result:

```
{
  "site": [
    [
      "site 'TRT' "
    ]
  ],
  "alias": [
    [
      " alias 'TRT,FAK,FAS,ATI,ONE,DVZ,TWO' "
    ]
  ],
  "server": [
    [
      " serveur 'Test10011' RAS "
    ]
  ],
  "msg": [
    [
      ""
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am not able to parse the last few items in the 'msg', . Could you please help ,where I'm going wrong? msg should contain "TRT / TRT serveur 'Test10011' OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just need to use `GREEDYDATA` instead of `DATA` pattern:

```
%{DATA:site}\s*:\s*%{DATA:alias}\s*:\s*%{DATA:server}\s*:\s*%{GREEDYDATA:msg}
```

I also suggest adding `\s*` around `:` to get rid of leading/trailing whitespaces.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor. Didn't consider GREEDYDATA before :)

Comment: Yeah, `GREEDYDATA` is translated to the `.*` pattern (a *greedy* dot matching pattern), and `DATA` is translated into `.*?` (lazy dot matching pattern). You may read more about [greedy and lazy quantifiers here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html).

Comment: One last thing. In case if I want only 'OK' in 'msg' label how would I remove the characters before OK?

Comment: If that word is always at the end and is always preceded with a space, replace the last `\s*` with `.*\s` (`%{DATA:site}\s*:\s*%{DATA:alias}\s*:\s*%{DATA:server}\s*:.*\s%{GREEDYDATA:msg}`)